# can't charge phone after last elementary base update

Tags: release-freya, updates

I used to charge my phone (Moto G3) connecting it to my laptop. It was working fine until I installed an elementary base update last week. My phone no longer gets charged. I thought it was a problem with my cable or USB port(s) or even the phone's port. But it works fine when using a regular charger, or while booted in to windows in the same machine.

Comment: elementary OS charges my Nexus 9 (though very slowly which is normal for my device when charging from laptop). It even charges it before elementary OS has booted

Comment: I do not think that this is related to elementary since your phone is charged by USB power which I think elementary OS cannot control